# In modules over finite rings $Rv = Rw \iff R^\times v = R^\times w$

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

> Let $R$ be a finite ring (with unit, possibly non-commutative), and $M$ a left module over $R$. Let $v,w\in M$. Then
>   $$Rv = Rw \iff R^\times v = R^\times w.$$

This follows from Lemma 6.4 in [Hyman Bass. K-theory and stable algebra. Publications Mathématiques de l'Institut des Hautes Études Scientifiques 22 (1964), 5–60](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02684689).

The proof uses the Artin-Wedderburn classification theorem. My question is if there is a simpler proof. (The hard part is the direction $\Rightarrow$, of course.)

As a remark, the statement is not true any more for infinite rings. Counterexamples with $M={}_R R$ can be found on page 466 in [Irving Kaplansky. Elementary divisors and modules. Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 66 (1949), 464–491](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1949-0031470-3). Counterexamle (b) is over a commutative Noetherian ring $R$.

Comment: What portions of the theory of semisimple rings (or modules) would you permit in a solution?

Comment: @MannyReyes: The less, the better. Ideally, none. The statement does not involve the notion *semisimple*. So I'd hope for a proof wich does not rely on the theory of semisimple rings/modules at all.

Answer (score 5):

Let $r,s\in R$ with $rv=w$ and $sw=v$. Since $R$ is finite, there exists $n>0$ such that $f=(rs)^n$ and $e=(sr)^n$ are idempotent.  Note that $ev=v$ and $fw=w$.  Let $r'=fre$ and $s'=esf$.  Notice that $r'v=w$.  Also note that right multiplication by $r'$ gives an $R$-module homomorphism $Rf\to Re$.  In fact, it is surjective (as is easily verified using the definitions of $e,f,r'$).  Similarly right multiplication by $s'$ gives a surjective $R$-module homomorphism $Re\to Rf$.  By finiteness of $R$ we conclude both these homomorphisms are isomorphisms.  It follows that $R(1-f)\cong R(1-e)$ by the Krull-Schmidt theorem (I don't know if this counts as more or less elementary than Wedderburn-Artin).  Such an isomorphism is given by right multiplication by an element $x\in (1-f)R(1-e)$.

Consider $u=r'+x$.  Then $u$ is a unit since right multiplication by $u$ gives an isomorphism from $R=Rf\oplus R(1-f)$ to $R=Re\oplus R(1-e)$ (as it is the direct sum of the two isos $Rf\to Re$ and $R(1-f)\to R(1-e)$) and in a finite ring an element with a one-sided inverse is invertible.    Also $uv=(r'+x)v=(r'+x)ev=r'ev=r'v=w$ because $x\in (1-f)R(1-e)$ implies $xe=0$.  Thus $w\in R^\times v$.

Comment: Why is $R/Re \cong R/Rf $ ?

Comment: Good point. Let me think.

Comment: OK. I need the fact that for an artinian ring Re is isomorphic to Rf iff R(1-e) is ISO to R(1-f)

Comment: @darijgrinberg, the answer to your question is Krull-Schmidt.  Since $R=Re\oplus R(1-e)=Rf\oplus R(1-f)$, if $Re\cong Rf$, then Krull-Schmidt guarantees $R(1-1)\cong R(1-f)$.